# ASP.NET MVC. Code First Parent navigational property not populated automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, navigation-properties

Given these POCO classes

```
class MainClass{

    [Key] int id {get;set;}

    public string name {get;set;}

    [Required] 
    public virtual ICollection<SubItem> subItems {get;set} // unique sub items

}
```

and

```
Class SubItem{

    [Key] int id {get; set;}

    public string name {get;set;}

    [Required] // required is nedded. the subitem cannot exist by it's self
    public MainClass parent {get; set;}
}
```

When posting and binding it into controller, it all set, and I set all SubItems state to:

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit([Bind()] MainClass entity) {
    foreach(var subItem in entity.subItems)
        db.Entry(subItem).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

    if (ModelState.IsValid) { // Fails here
        db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { edited = "true" });
    }

}
```

However modelState contains "parent cannot be null" error for each item.
and validations fails. For some reason the "parent" property are not automatically populated. How can I avoid it?

I'm rendering the view like this.

```
@model MainClass
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.id)
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.name)
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.subItems)
```

Where SubItem has the fallowing `EditorTemplate`

```
@model SubItem
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.id)
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.name)
```

and `[Required] parent` is needed due cascade deleting.

**Without the `[Required]` everything works good. And the parent property are added when db is saved. However cascade deleting is turned off on migration.**

Comment: How are you rendering the properties for `parent` in the view?

Comment: what is `Entity` here? `Entity.subItems` ?

Comment: @Sampath I edited the question

Comment: @StephenMuecke I edited the question adding it

Comment: Your not generating any controls for `parent` in the `EditorTemplate` (and you should not need to anyway). You `SubItem` should have a navigation property for the `MainClass` (say) `int MainClassId` and remove the `[Required]` property from `MainClass parent`. Then you can add `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.MainClassId)` in the `EditorTemplate` (or just assign its value before you call the database)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the `[Required] parent`  is needed due cascade deleting.
I will try adding the hidden field and the navigation one property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke What do you mean by "or just assign its value before you call the database"

Comment: Your rendering the `id` property of `MainClass` in the view, so in the POST method you can get it and use `foreach(var subItem in entity.subItems) { subItem.MainClassId = entity.id; ..... }`

Comment: I think it'd be better if you used different classes for the view, other than the one you use for Entity Framework. Create a `MainClassViewModel` class and same for SubItem, so in the view model classes you add whatever data annotation you need for validation, thus you wouldn't need the parent reference (only Id, as suggested by @StephenMuecke). Then in your classes, you use the navigation property to parent with `[Required]`. You'd just need to assign values from your `view models` to your `entities model` and save it with EF.